# Defining JRE used by maven plug-in in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-plugin

I've been sentenced to Java development using a Windows machine where I'm not admin.

This machine has three JREs installed (all 1.8 at various levels).

- Two "official" ones that I cannot alter
- A bootl^H^H^H^H^H "development" JDK/JRE that I can alter at will.

Of course there are system-wide `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` settings that point to one of the two official ones and that I cannot change (or override with user settings).

For maven builds I have to use a company maven repository that has an HTTPS certificate signed with a company root certificate. This company root certificate isn't included in the `cacerts` of the two official JREs. If I run the maven builds using the default JRE, I get certificate errors.

But of course I can (and did) add the company root certificate to the `cacerts` of the "development" JRE.

Then, setting JAVA_HOME and PATH properly in a command prompt, I can run maven builds using the development JRE (as controlled using `mvn -version`) and this retrieves artifacts from the company repository without problems.

Of course I use an IDE, Eclipse (2018_12_R) in this case. I can (I think...) start Eclipse with the "development" JRE using `eclipse -vm "\path\to\dev\jre\bin\javaw.exe"`. This is confirmed using  `Help>About>Installation details` that shows `eclipse.vm=\path\to\dev\jre\bin\javaw.exe` (and many references to that JRE elsewhere and no references to any of the "official" JREs).

I have added the m2e plugin (1.10.0.20181127-2120). But this plugin is unable to retrieve artifacts from the repository, and complains about an unverifiable certificate (the plugin works correctly otherwise, but I have to do "external" maven builds to fetch new artifacts). So there are two possibilities:

1. The plugin is not using the "development" JRE:

   - how can I check this a bit more directly
   - how can I force it to use the right one
2. The plugin isn't using the regular cacerts file:

   - how can I change this
   - or how can I add the company root certificate to that collection?

Thanks for any enlightenment.

Edit:

- `Preferences>Maven>Installations` says it is using `EMBEDDED 3.5./1.10.0.20181127-2120`. There is a small note at the bottom of that panel that says "Embedded runtime is always used for dependency resolution".

Comment: Your Eclipse is two years and 8 releases behind. Eclipse is shipped with Maven support, at least the Java IDE packages. In _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_ configure the installed JREs/JDKs and in the Maven launch configuration, in the tab _JRE_ choose which Java should be used to run the Maven build.

Comment: I'm using the tools they give me... Now I managed to have only the "development" Java active in Eclipse (it doesn't list any other JRE) and the Maven run configuration says that's the one used. Despite this, "maven install" in Eclipse still fails with `Hostname the.corporate.repo not verified` while the command-line "mvn install" works.

Comment: When you able to install a plugin, you can also upgrade Eclipse.